# How to display category image in $_menu or _getHtml function and apply to vertical menu in magento

Tags: image, magento, menu, categories

as i am new to magenta(o) and i bought a magenta(o) theme, i want to display category image and apply them to my vertical menu. If i take a look to my vertical menu file, it only calls $_menu which means it calls the categories i made on magenta(o) dashboard, i want to show the image on the category list on vertical menu. Please tell me how to show them programmatically

```
if($childLevel < 1 ){
     $img_urls = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$child->getData('thumbnail');
     $img = '<img src="'.$img_urls.'" />';
     }

     $html .= '<li ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
     $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>'
     . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . '</span> '.$img.' </a>';
```

i found that function which calls $_menu, please tell me what i should add/update on that function

Answer (score 0):

Override App/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php in your any of the local modules and modify "_getHtml" function as following :

```
<?php

protected function _getHtml(Varien_Data_Tree_Node $menuTree, $childrenWrapClass)
    {
        $html = '';

        $children = $menuTree->getChildren();
        $parentLevel = $menuTree->getLevel();
        $childLevel = is_null($parentLevel) ? 0 : $parentLevel + 1;

        $counter = 1;
        $childrenCount = $children->count();

        $parentPositionClass = $menuTree->getPositionClass();
        $itemPositionClassPrefix = $parentPositionClass ? $parentPositionClass . '-' : 'nav-';
        // Category model
        $categoryModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        foreach ($children as $child) {

            //get category thumbnail and its image url
            $categoryThumbnailRelativePath = $categoryModel->load($child->getId())->getThumbnail();
            $categoryThumbnailUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$categoryThumbnailRelativePath(); 

            $child->setLevel($childLevel);
            $child->setIsFirst($counter == 1);
            $child->setIsLast($counter == $childrenCount);
            $child->setPositionClass($itemPositionClassPrefix . $counter);

            $outermostClassCode = '';
            $outermostClass = $menuTree->getOutermostClass();

            if ($childLevel == 0 && $outermostClass) {
                $outermostClassCode = ' class="' . $outermostClass . '" ';
                $child->setClass($outermostClass);
            }

            $html .= '<li ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
            $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>'
                . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . '</span></a>';

            //append the thumbnail image on frontend
            $html .= '<img class="categoryImage" alt="'.$child->getName().'" src="'.$categoryThumbnailUrl.'">';

            if ($child->hasChildren()) {
                if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) {
                    $html .= '<div class="' . $childrenWrapClass . '">';
                }
                $html .= '<ul class="level' . $childLevel . '">';
                $html .= $this->_getHtml($child, $childrenWrapClass);
                $html .= '</ul>';
                 if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) {
                    $html .= '</div>';
                }
            }
            $html .= '</li>';

            $counter++;
        }

        return $html;
    }
```